# Taekwondo belts and their rankings

Tags: tae-kwon-do, belt, grading

What are the rankings of the 6 taekwondo belts and how long does it take to get those belts?

Comment: To which Taekwondo organization are you referring? Each one will have a different sequence of colored ranks, followed by black belt ranks. Each one usually also distinguishes between child rank and adult rank. This information is generally available by searching on Google.

Comment: I've never known one with just 6, but if I were to guess, White, Yellow, Green, Brown, Red, Black is most likely. But won't someone think of the camo belt? As for how long it takes to get them, I'm pretty sure Amazon has overnight shipping. By drones in some areas.

Comment: And don't forget, you can have stripes down the whole belt (length-wise). And you can have stripes that get taped to the ends of the belt. Like my old TKD school did white, yellow, yellow 1 stripe, orange, orange 1 stripe, green, green 1-3 stripes, blue, blue 1-3 stripes, red, red 1-3 stripes, brown, brown 1-3 stripes, black, black 1-9 stripes. The stripes on colored rank required passing tests, or you could test into the stripes. Like when I tested for yellow belt, I went from white belt to yellow with 1 stripe. This was good for business and student retention apparently. Win-win.

Comment: see also [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/3117/1618)

Comment: For times, also see [Belt advancement speed in Taekwondo](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/1575/5961)